# dtype argument in np.genfromtxt and StringIO

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

numpy.genfromtxt on scipy page shows the following code. I cannot make sense of the following code especially the dtype and reading the string part and, therefore the code. The following is the code.

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
s=StringIO(u"1,1.3,abced")
data=np.genfromtxt(s, dtype=[('myint', 'i8'),('myfloat','f8'), ('mystring','S5')], delimiter=",")
```

Ok. Here, I get that 1,1.3 and abced is being read from `s=StringIO(u"1,1.3,abced")`. But what does `u` do?

Also, I get that i8 is integer for 8 bytes. But what do '`myint`', '`myfloat`' and '`mystring`' do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'u' is for 'unicode', the default string type in Py3, so it isn't needed here.  Also the `StringIO` isn't needed either.  I just give `genfromtxt` a list of strings:

```
In [221]: txt = ["1,1.3,abced"]

In [223]: np.genfromtxt(txt, 
  dtype=[('myint', 'i8'),('myfloat','f8'), ('mystring','S5')], 
  delimiter=",")
Out[223]: 
array((1, 1.3, b'abced'),
     dtype=[('myint', '<i8'), ('myfloat', '<f8'), ('mystring', 'S5')])
```

The `dtype` defines a compound dtype, one with 3 fields, one for each column.  You access fields by name:

```
data['myint']
data['myfloat']
```